# DAX function that check if value is in range and return corresponding value in other table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables: a "Range" table that has the ranges and its corresponding values and a "Data" table that has the values I want to check against the ranges.

My Data table is as follows, but it has more rows than the Range table. The "PM" values are the ones that I need to check.

```
Location PM
B01      1,05
B02      1,04888
B15      1,05787
B16      1,05787
B03      2,03714
B04      2,03714
B09      2,03714
B10      2,03714
B17      2,03714
```

And the "Range" table is like this sample:

```
P.E     P.S     PV
0,48    1,03    10,00%
1,03    2,02    10,03%
2,02    3,63    8,87%
3,63    6,23    8,24%
6,23    10,17   7,62%
10,17   15,79   6,46%
15,79   22,37   5,75%
22,37   30,70   5,29%
30,70   41,27   4,99%
41,27   54,88   4,86%
54,88   71,57   4,65%
```

So, summing up, I need to create a DAX measure or column that checks if the PM value is between the PE and PS values and return the corresponding PV.

On excel, I managed to do this usind the LOOKUP function, as this function rounds the searched value to the nearest smaller value in the corresponding table to give a match. On Power Bi I coudn't find a way to replicate this.

Does someone knows if it's possible?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a **measure** as below-

```
respected_pv = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(range[PV]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(range),
        range[P.E] <= MIN(data[PM])
            && range[P.S] >= MIN(data[PM])
    )
)
```

Here is the code for a **Custom Column**-

```
respected_pv_column = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(range[PV]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(range),
        range[P.E] <= data[PM]
            && range[P.S] >= data[PM]
    )
)
```

Here below is the sample output. Remember, only first row get the PV as other ranges are not available in your sample data.

[image]